# How to change font size dynamically when resize the row header in datagridview using c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to change font size dynamically when resize the row header in datagridview.

Comment: On resize bind jquery event, in the event you can change the font size, else in code behind.

Comment: Its windows application..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 private void dataGridView1_RowHeightChanged(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        float width =e.Row.Height-3;
        dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", width, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);              
    }
```

In float width=e.Row.Height-3, 3 is your value whatever you want.. I think this is useful....